# AWS DataSync Agent Key Generation with VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-datasync

I'm trying to activate my KVM Agent using a VPC Endpoint.

I first enter "0" to get the activation key:

[image]

Then I enter select the region ("us-east-1"), the service endpoint ("3") and it asks me for the private IpV4 address:

[image]

What am I supposed to enter for this? Here is the details of my VPC Endpoint I created:

[image]

I've been looking at the documentation such as these links, but it isn't very detailed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/activate-agent.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/local-console-vm.html#get-activation-key